# ls on device without mounting it

Tags: linux, mount, ls

Is it possible to run `ls` on a device without mounting it first?
Something like this:

```
# ls /dev/sda1
```

Comment: On what purpose?

Comment: I don't think so. You'd definitely need a tool besides `ls`.

Comment: No. Why don't you tell us what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: for those times I want to mount some device but don't remember if its sda1/2/3/4/5/6 etc. Just needs to list the files on that device to give me a clue whether its the device i'm looking for

Comment: By the way: if you have an image of a disk (not a partition), you may be able to see its files on [`testdisk`](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) by running the `testdisk` command with an image file path as its first parameter on the command line.

Answer (score 11):

You can using the `debugfs` program of [e2fsprogs](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/). Despite its historical name, it will work on ext2/3/4 filesystems. The usage is simple:

```
# debugfs -R "ls -l" /dev/sda6
  2   40755 (2)   1001   1001    4096 17-Sep-2013 04:03 .
  2   40755 (2)   1001   1001    4096 17-Sep-2013 04:03 ..
 16  100644 (1)   1001   1001    9085 17-Sep-2013 04:03 avserver.conf
 17  100644 (1)   1001   1001    2177 17-Sep-2013 04:03 bash.bashrc
 26  100644 (1)   1001   1001     722 17-Sep-2013 04:03 crontab
 …
```

where "ls -l" is a `debugfs` specific command that acts mostly like `ls -l`; you can't use any arbitrary shell command there. By default, debugfs opens a drive in read-only mode so this is relatively safe; for example trying this on a non ext2/3/4 partition just gives a diagnostic:

```
# debugfs -R "ls -l" /dev/sda2
/dev/sda2: Bad magic number in super-block while opening filesystem
ls: Filesystem not open
```

I can't say I consider this recommendable practice, but it will do what you ask.

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of mounting a filesystem is to access its files. So no, in general, you can't access the files of a filesystem without mounting it.

There are a few utilities that access a file directly without mounting, such as [debugfs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/debugfs) for ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystems and [mtools](http://www.gnu.org/software/mtools/) for FAT filesystems.

For an ext2/ext3/ext4, rather than invoke the dangerous and hard to use program `debugfs`, you can list its last mount location:

```
tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep 'Last mounted'
```

However this is only useful if the last mount location has been recorded.

Most filesystem types support giving the filesystems labels (e.g. `tune2fs -L foo`). So give all your filesystems a unique label. Then mount the filesystem by label:

```
mount /dev/disks/by-label/foo /media/foo
```

or

```
mount LABEL=foo /media/foo
```

Answer (score 3):

As earlier described, debugfs works well.

```
debugfs -R "ls -l" /dev/sda1
```

For NTFS, there's ntfsls from ntfs-3g.

```
ntfsls /dev/sda2
```

For FAT, there's mdir, from mtools.

```
mdir -i /dev/sdc1
```

For exFAT I'm not sure though. Seems exfat-utils does not include any tools similar to the ones described above. There's dumpexfat though, but I don't think it'll provide the information asked for.

To find out more details about attached drives, there's lsblk.

```
lsblk
```

Personally I prefer this, and have set an alias for it:

```
alias lsblk="lsblk -o MODEL,TRAN,NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE,MAJ:MIN"
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: you cannot. `ls` uses standard libc routines which translate into system calls that are served by the file system driver, hence it's not possible to use `ls` (or anything using those system calls for that matter) without mounting the file system.

You could write a utility that would circumvent this by having its own copy of some parts of the file system driver (such thing exists e.g. for reading Ext2 file systems from Windows), but that is quite impractical.

If your problem is just identifying the partitions, you probably should start using [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) which has space for partition names (72 bytes per partition). Some overlying solutions (Linux MD or LVM for example) allow naming as well.